# How to check if Here Maps API is loaded?

Tags: javascript

How to check if `Here Maps API` is loaded in the form?

I do not want to execute mapping scripts if the MAP API already excuted in the form. Once the MAP appears I don't want it should again call the map API and create a new map instead of replacing that map.

Comment: how is the here maps API loaded in the first place? you've shown zip/nada/diddly code, so

Comment: Is it google map or here map..?

Comment: I am using Here Map.So how can i restrict to create a new map instead of replace. I am calling map API in button call.

Comment: so a button call didn't have var map declaration you can declare it globaly and check if its undefined then only create new

Comment: var map_value = document.getElementById('mapContainer').value;
alert(map_value);
if(map_value == undefined)
{
departure();
arrival();
}
else{
alert('do nothing');
}
Yes i wrote the above code but again if i click on button it is creating a new map. please suggest

Comment: Where do you initialise map first..? Check my answer..

Comment: `var map_value = document.getElementById('mapContainer').value;` didn't give you map. You have to check for `map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer'), maptypes.normal.map,   {
      zoom: 10,
      center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
    });`

Comment: I have updated my answer you can check..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this..

```js
// Initialize the platform object:
    
    var map;
    function CreateMap(){
    alert(map);
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    'app_id': '{YOUR_APP_ID} ',
    'app_code': '{YOUR_APP_CODE} '
    });

    // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
    var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
    if(map == undefined){
    map = new H.Map(
    document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
    maptypes.normal.map,
    {
      zoom: 10,
      center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
    });
    }
    else{
    return;
    }
   }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
  <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"
  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"
  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="button" onclick="CreateMap();" value="CreateMap"/>
  <div style="width: 640px; height: 480px" id="mapContainer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your quick response..It resolved my issue..Thanks

Comment: If it do then you can upvote and accept my answer for future users